# Trouble with Google API RSS and Slideshow

Tags: rss, google-api, slideshow

Our website: https://www.anticancerclub.com/

I am using some Google API RSS Feed code in the middle of our page (titles are "What's New", "Food for Thought", "Tell Your Story"). I also have a slideshow (s3slider) in the top left corner of the content area on the home page. Neither of which are showing in all browsers.

When I go to the page using Firefox (v.22) I can see them both. But when I go to the page in IE (v.10), Chrome (v.28), or Safari (v.5.1.7) they do not appear.

Is this because the site is using an SSL (https://) and the slideshow and rss feeds are not secure? Ironically this is Google API and it doesn't work in Chrome.

Here is the code for the RSS Feed:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

google.load("feeds", "1");

function OnLoad() {
  // Create a feed control
  var feedControl = new google.feeds.FeedControl();

  // Add three feeds.

  feedControl.addFeed("http://accnutritionalbootcamp.com/accblog/?feed=rss2", "What's New");
  feedControl.addFeed("http://www.accnutritionalbootcamp.com/?feed=rss2", "Food For Thought");
  feedControl.addFeed("http://www.accnutritionalbootcamp.com/mystory/?feed=rss2", "Tell Your Story");

  // Draw it.
  feedControl.draw(document.getElementById("my_feed")); // Sends info to <div id="#my_feed"></div> on homepage.
}

google.setOnLoadCallback(OnLoad);

</script>
```

Here is the code for the Slideshow:

```
 <!-- IMAGE SLIDER JavaScripts-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://s3slider-original.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/s3Slider.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function() { 
                  $('#s3slider').s3Slider({
                       timeOut: 4000
                   });
               });
    </script>
<!-- END IMAGE SLIDER JavaScripts-->

<!-- IMAGE SLIDER HTML -->
<td colspan="2" width="300" height="215">
<div id="s3slider">
    <ul id="s3sliderContent">
        <li class="s3sliderImage">
           <a href="http://www.anticancerclub.com/SearchResults.asp?Cat=1969" title="Nutrition"> <img src="http://rquox.pzldq.servertrust.com/v/vspfiles/photos/slider/slide1.jpg"></a>
<span> <a href="http://www.anticancerclub.com/SearchResults.asp?Cat=1969" title="Nutrition" style="color:#ffffff !important;">Nutrition</a></span>
        </li>
        <li class="s3sliderImage">
            <img src="http://rquox.pzldq.servertrust.com/v/vspfiles/photos/slider/slide2.jpg">
<span>Exercise</span>
        </li>
        <li class="s3sliderImage">
             <a href="http://www.anticancerclub.com/SearchResults.asp?Cat=1919" title="Stress Management">  <img src="http://rquox.pzldq.servertrust.com/v/vspfiles/photos/slider/slide3.jpg"></a>
<span> <a href="http://www.anticancerclub.com/SearchResults.asp?Cat=1919" title="Stress Management" style="color:#ffffff !important;">Stress Management</a></span>
        </li>
        <li class="s3sliderImage">
             <a href="http://www.anticancerclub.com/SearchResults.asp?Cat=1989" title="Connection">  <img src="http://rquox.pzldq.servertrust.com/v/vspfiles/photos/slider/slide4.jpg"></a>
<span> <a href="http://www.anticancerclub.com/SearchResults.asp?Cat=1989" title="Connection" style="color:#ffffff !important;">Connection</a></span>
        </li>
        <div class="clear s3sliderImage"></div>
    </ul>
</div>
</td>
  <!-- END IMAGE SLIDER -->
```

Any help with this matter would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Really, no one knows why google's API won't work in Chrome, IE or Safari?

Comment: Still no ideas??? Can anyone help?